# Different license for logo files

Tags: licensing, gpl

I'm working on software that I intend to release under the terms of the GPL 3. However, I'd like to exempt the name and logo: the images with the logo should only be used with official releases, and only the official releases should be allowed to use the original project name. Forks should use a different name and logo to avoid confusion.

How do I specify this license modification in my project's documentation?

Comment: What if you just *don't include the name and logo* in the public GPL repository that you're distributing publicly. In other words, in the public GPL version you just put "FooWare" and "FooLogo". And in your official release, your customers see "BarWare (r)" and "BarLogo (r)" and perhaps you can offer other services like support contracts or whatever on that version. To satisfy GPL requirements to your customers of the official, of course you can supply source code to GPL components.

Comment: Maybe the GPL just isn't for you, but there are plenty other free-ish licenses to pick from. For example, the Mozilla Firefox name is trademarked, although the code is open source. This works due to the Mozilla Public License that allows FLOSS code to be combined with non-free files such as the Firefox logo. Because this approach is incompatible with a strict interpretation of free software, the Debian Linux distro includes a rebranded “Iceweasel” browser that's uses exactly the same code as Firefox, but ships with a FLOSS-compatible name and logo.

Comment: Note that if you own all the code, you can release it multiple times under different licenses if you want. However if you built it by incorporating someone else's GPL code, you would need their permission to relicense it.

Comment: I do want to release the whole project publicly, I don't intend to offer any commercial services or something like that. Maybe I should just put the logo under GPL as well and stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the issue of having un-intended consequences if you dis-allow the logo and name from being used in "non-official releases"

For example, if lets say debian was to branch your project to include in their distro (without modification), or I choose to provide a compiled binary version which is compatible with raspberry pi. In both of those cases your project might not have any modification. Would these be acceptable options for you ?

A "Sly" way of protecting your logo and name would be to trademark them and then have a additional licence for their acceptable use (but be aware that in the event that if your trademark is infringed in some manner then you *MUST* defend it in court otherwise it can be considered lost)

Answer (score 3):

Names and logos are actually covered by trademark law, not copyright law (in almost all cases). If you want to stop someone from passing a derivative off as your project, the solution is to enforce a trademark on the name and logo; trademark is all about preventing confusion between your product and other products, while copyright is about preventing someone from making an exact copy of your creative work. Furthermore, the name actually probably *can't* be copyrighted, and the logo may well not be copyrightable.

The GPL v3 actually explicitly supports this, assuming you're the sole copyright holder on the code or have permission from the other holders. Section 7 allows specific sorts of additional restrictions which are allowed if the copyright holders all agree; one such restriction is declining to grant trademark rights for various trademarks in the program. While a derivative would be allowed to contain your logo in its files, they couldn't use the logo or your name to identify the program. This seems to achieve your goals.

The relevant text from section 7 of the [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) is as follows:

> c) Prohibiting misrepresentation of the origin of that material, or
>   requiring that modified versions of such material be marked in
>   reasonable ways as different from the original version; or
>
> e) Declining to grant rights under trademark law for use of some trade
>   names, trademarks, or service marks; or